# How to provide usage information for npm scripts

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, npm-scripts

Is there an easy way to provide usage information for npm scripts?

Ideally, when I run `npm run`, I would get output like this (note the description at bottom of each task):

```
Lifecycle scripts included in product-discovery-service:
  start
    node server.js

available via `npm run-script`:
  watch
    run-p watch:build watch:run
    Run in development mode and rebuild/restart when changes are made
  watch:build
    npm run build:dev -- --watch
    Probably don't need this (would be nice to be able to omit tasks like this)
  watch:run
    nodemon --watch build/ --inspect
    Probably don't need this (would be nice to be able to omit tasks like this)
  prewatch:run
    wait-on --log build/server.js
    Probably don't need this (would be nice to be able to omit tasks like this)
  build
    babel server.js --out-dir build/
    Build the project
  prebuild
    rimraf build/
    Probably don't need this (would be nice to be able to omit tasks like this)
  build:dev
    npm run build -- --source-maps
    Probably don't need this (would be nice to be able to omit tasks like this)
```

It looks like npm doesn't support this, but maybe there's a third-party with a solution? I found [npm-scripts-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-scripts-help), but it feels clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer:

Yes you're correct, npm does not provide a built-in feature to include descriptions when running `npm run`. So, any solution you choose will have some level of *"feels clunky"* associated with it.

As you've mentioned 
[npm-scripts-help](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-scripts-help) is a package which can achieve this. I'm not aware of other similar third-party solutions.

---

#### Alternative custom solution:

The following steps describe how to write a simple custom Nodejs utility script (without using another third-party package dependency). This script can then be invoked via npm-scripts.

1. Create a simple Nodejs utility script as follows. Lets name the file `usage.js`.

   **usage.js**

   ```
   const usage = `
     Lifecycle scripts included in ${process.env.npm_package_name}:
     start
       node server.js

   available via \`npm run-script\`:
     watch
       run-p watch:build watch:run
       Run in development mode and rebuild/restart when changes are made
     watch:build
       npm run build:dev -- --watch
       Probably don't need this (would be nice to be able to omit tasks like this)
     watch:run
       nodemon --watch build/ --inspect
       ...`

   console.log('%s', usage);
   ```
2. Save `usage.js` in your projects root directory at the same level where `package.json` is stored.
3. Add the following `usage` script to the `scripts` section of your `package.json`:

   ```json
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "usage": "node usage",
     ...
   },
   ...
   ```
4. Run `npm run usage` to print the usage info to the console. A script name (i.e. `usage`) has to be provided with `npm run`. Unfortunately your ideal of just running `npm run` will only log npm's simple log - which doesn't include descriptions.

**Notes:**

- On line two in `usage.js` we reference the package name variable via the part which reads: `${process.env.npm_package_name}`
- If you change the location of where `usage.json` is stored in your project directory you'll need to redifine the path to it in your npm-script as required. For example, if you choose to store it in a folder named `scripts`, which resides in your projects root directory, then your `usage` script should be defined as follows:

  ```json
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "usage": "node scripts/usage",
    ...
  },
  ...
  ```

---

**Adding ANSI/VT100 Control sequences**

You can utilize [ANSI/VT100 Control sequences](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) in `usage.js` to add colors and formatting to the usage log.

For example, in the  following `usage.js`, the codes:

- `\x1b[1m`
- `\x1b[0m`

...are utilized to embolden code snippets and reset the formatting back to default respectively.

Tip: If cross-platform is a requirement I suggest using the *ANSI 8/16 Colors* (listed at the previous link) only. The formatting codes for *bold* (`\x1b[1m`) do not work in Windows cmd.exe using terminals such as *Windows Command Prompt* or *PowerShell*.

**usage.js** (with formatting)

```
const BOLD = '\x1b[1m';
const NORM = '\x1b[0m';

const formattedUsage = `
Lifecycle scripts included in ${BOLD}${process.env.npm_package_name}:${NORM}
  ${BOLD}start
    node server.js${NORM}

available via ${BOLD}npm run-script${NORM}
  ${BOLD}watch
    run-p watch:build watch:run${NORM}
    Run in development mode and rebuild/restart when changes are made
  ${BOLD}watch:build
    npm run build:dev -- --watch${NORM}
    ...`

console.log('%s', formattedUsage);
```

You could also consider combining [ES6 Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) and [package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) to reference the values of each npm-script. For example:

```js
`${BOLD}${process.env.npm_package_scripts_watch}:${NORM}`
```

Comment: Thanks @RobC - given no better alternative, I was actually thinking of doing the same thing you're suggesting with a separate `usage` script.